# Screen lock on Ubuntu 18.04 goes to switch user

Tags: 18.04, lightdm, lock

I have a new Ubuntu 18.04 installation using lightdm and ubuntu-desktop.    Other than root, users are set up via an LDAP server.

If I log on as a regular user, I get the desktop w/o issue.    If I <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, the screen locks like it is supposed to.     No problem.

But, if I go to the lock button in the power menu (upper right corner), the system performs a switch user and takes me to another log in.    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> takes me back to the unlocked original session.

So, what is different about the way that <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> locks and the button does?

The questions I have been reading generally discuss disabling the lock feature.   Since this is a shared lab, that is not an option.

Other info:   Under 16.04 in the same lab, both options lock the screen correctly.     I have also tried to use gdm3 with the Ubuntu 18.04 setup, but haven't been able to get LDAP to play nice with it, in case any one wonders why I am using lightdm.    And, if I log in with the plasma desktop, locking is fine.     I am hoping the nexus of information might trigger something for someone out there.

thanks